# ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Error adding new user to database

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I am using gcloud oauth2.0 to access it and store it in new database. But I am getting this weird error:

> ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Error adding new user to
>   database. (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   ab_user.email

Some more log details:

> [SQL: INSERT INTO ab_user (first_name, last_name, username, password,
>   active, email, last_login, login_count, fail_login_count, created_on,
>   changed_on, created_by_fk, changed_by_fk) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] [parameters: ('Shivam', 'Sahil',
>   'some secret string',
>   'another secret string',
>   1, 'myemail@gmail.com', None, None, None, '2020-06-04
>   11:45:01.756574', '2020-06-04 11:45:01.756582', None, None)]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.manager:Error creating a new OAuth user google_<>

As the error says *UNIQUE constraint failed*, initially I thought my account is pre-registered and since I am trying to re-register it that's why I am getting this error, but here's the deal, when I tried to login using oauth authentication, this is what I am getting:

> ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Error adding new user to
>   database. (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   ab_user.email [SQL: INSERT INTO ab_user (first_name, last_name,
>   username, password, active, email, last_login, login_count,
>   fail_login_count, created_on, changed_on, created_by_fk,
>   changed_by_fk) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
>   [parameters: ('Shivam', 'Sahil', 'google_',
>   '',
>   1, 'myemail@gmail.com', None, None, None, '2020-06-04
>   11:57:19.778402', '2020-06-04 11:57:19.778409', None, None)]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
>   ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.manager:Error creating a new OAuth
>   user google_

I see both of them as the same error, has anyone done any research on this before? Any idea what's going wrong here? I have checked the authentication part well and google authentication page responds correctly on registration or wrong information feed. But even though it gets all the response this error shows up. Any help is highly appreciated!

Flask manager file can be found here: [manager.py](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py) (In case you're looking for code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue, Had a very silly problem, was trying to oauth register with an email which I already registered in the database using database authentication.